# Using the same proof for two subgoals in Coq

Tags: coq

After an induction on an inductive type, I have two subgoals to prove. The hypotheses and goals are slightly different but can be solved by the same (long) proof, which currently looks likes this:

```
induction x.
{
  admit.
}
{
  <long proof>
}
{
  <copy-paste of long proof>
}
```

Is there a way to avoid this copy-paste and keep the interactivity, for example by writing something similar to the following?

```
induction x.
{
  admit.
}
all:
{
  <long proof>
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes you can solve these goals with an intermediate lemma:

```
assert (H : statement_of_lemma).
{ 
  proof...
}
```

Later, you just have to apply `H` to each subcase.